# Sql to calculate number of days between two dates excluding Weekends and dates in holidays table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am new to Oracle Sql developer (11g).  I was asked to bring back the number of business days between an add date and the current sysdate. The total numbers of days should excludes weekends as well as days listed under a calendar table as holidays. Here are samples of the tables:

```
Process Request 
ID  Added_date
1   20-Feb-15
2   12-Dec-14
3   11-Nov-14
```

Holiday Table:

```
Holiday_date
1-Jan-15
19-Jan-15
16-Feb-15
```

Thanks.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @JackManey.. My apologies I forgot to mention.  I have have gotten as far as getting the date differences between the sysdate and the added_date.

Comment: Okay, now how can you tell if a given date falls on a weekend?

Answer (score 0):

This is a (somewhat) complicated question, at least as far as I can see, because you have to retrieve all of the dates within a given date range, then examine each to see if it is a weekend day or if it is a holiday day. Here is how I would go about doing that:

```
WITH d1 AS (
    SELECT id, added_date
         , added_date + LEVEL AS range_date
      FROM process_request
   CONNECT BY added_date + LEVEL < TRUNC(SYSDATE+1)
       AND PRIOR id = id
       AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT d1.id, d1.added_date, TRUNC(SYSDATE), COUNT(*) AS business_day_cnt
  FROM d1
 WHERE TO_CHAR(d1.range_date) NOT IN ('SAT','SUN')
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM holiday_table ht
                     WHERE TRUNC(ht.holiday_date) = TRUNC(d1.range_date) )
 GROUP BY d1.id, d1.added_date
 ORDER BY id
```

I would put together a SQL Fiddle but I'm having issues connecting at the moment. In our CTE (`d1`) I'm using `CONNECT BY` and `LEVEL` to get all of the dates between `added_date` and today's date (including today's date but not `added_date`). I then get a count by `id` of all those days, excluding those days that are weekend days and those that correspond to the dates that are given in `HOLIDAY_TABLE`.

**UPDATE - [SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a61db/2)**